# Linux Case statement using numbers

Tags: linux, numbers, parameter-passing, case

Hi i'm trying to make a small script 
i would like to ping to my subnet from a certain number till another certain number for example 
however $2 and $3 isnt working. any ideas?

```
code:
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -lt 9000 ]
do
        case "$1" in 
        -$2-3) for i in 192.168.1.{$2..$3];do if ping -c1 -w1 &>/dev/null;then echo $i this one is up;fi; done
        shift shift;;

        -a) echo "hey just something random
       esac
done
```

and like the output could be like for example

> letstrythisbash.sh 65-74
>   192.168.1.65 this one is up
>   192.168.1.69 this one is up
>   192.168.1.72 this one is up

Answer (score 2):

You'll want a look at the [`seq` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/seq):

```
themel@kallisti: ~ $ for i in $(seq 69 73) ; do echo $i is a number ; done
69 is a number
70 is a number
71 is a number
72 is a number
73 is a number
```